# Need to set env vars from async functions before calling an api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to set env vars before calling an api but the data i need to get to set them is from async functions

```
process.env.ENVVAR1 = await someFunc('sdkflskdf');
process.env.ENVVAR2 = await someFunc('sdfsdsd');

const someapi = require('someapi');
someapi.init({ paramOne: 'val1', paramTwo: 'val2' });
someapi.method('zzzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy');
```

How can I make sure these env vars are set *before* someapi is called?

Comment: if all this code is within an `async` function, then your calls to `someapi` should only run once the environment variables are set

Comment: they are all in an async function but that does not appear to be happening

Comment: Then something else is the problem. Please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is within the same `async` block, then there should be no problem, as everything will execute in the same order in which it is defined:

```
(async() => {
    process.env.ENVVAR1 = await someFunc('sdkflskdf');
    process.env.ENVVAR2 = await someFunc('sdfsdsd');

    const someapi = require('someapi');
    someapi.init({ paramOne: 'val1', paramTwo: 'val2' });
    someapi.method('zzzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy');
})();
```

And if it doesn't work, then your API is included elsewhere, before the environment is set, and you are having some sort of initialization conflict.